# excluding bad lines in spring batch to ItemWriter

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

```
Cob Date;Supplier Code;Customer Code;
20180123;ABCLTD;43434;
20180123;BCD;4645;
;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;
```

How can I avoid passing lines with `;;;;;;`  to the writer?

My mapper class looks something like this:

```
public class Mapper implements FieldSetMapper<Model> {


    @Override
    public PosRow mapFieldSet(FieldSet fieldSet) {

        if (fieldSet == null) {
            return null;
        }

        Model pos = new Model();

        try {

            if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(fieldSet.readString("cobDate"))) {
                pos.setCobDate(new Date());
            }

            } catch(...) {}

            }
            return pos;
    }
```

I check for `fieldset==null` and then check for each delimited fields and set the values to model. Next, in my processor looks like this:

```
public class ModelItemProcessor implements ItemProcessor<Model, AnotherModel> {

    private Set<AnotherModel> anotherModelSet= new HashSet<>();

    @Override
    public AnotherModel process(final Model posRow) throws Exception {

        if (posRow == null) {

        }

        if (!posRow.isValid()) {
            return null;
        }


       AnotherModel scp = new AnotherModel();

      //sett values

        if (anotherModelSet.contains(scp)) return null;

        anotherModelSet.add(scp);

        return scp;
    }
```

but still in my `write()` method i get items that are of size 0.

Comment: It may drop to try/catch of mapFieldSet and then you are returning pos object.

Comment: yes, It was that. I resolved moving `isValid()` call to `mapField` set

Comment: Good to know it has done. Just for information, spring batch also gives an option to ignore errors in reader. Take a look if you can use so we can reduce coe

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your processor returns null when a record is invalid.  In your code, you're catching exceptions in the mapFieldSet() call, but you're returning an empty PosRow record.  Instead, try something like:

```
    try {

        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(fieldSet.readString("cobDate"))) {
            pos.setCobDate(new Date());
        }

        } 
        catch(...) {
            return null;
        }

        }
        return pos;
```